# TrueCrypt-ed Windows XP reseting administrative password

Tags: windows, truecrypt

I have inherited a laptop running Windows XP 64bit professional from a former system admin of my Lab. The laptop is encrypted with TrueCrypt and luckily I have a password for TrueCrypt and can boot and login into the guest account. However this is where my problems starts. There are four account on the laptop three of which do have administrative privileges. However nobody of two formers members of the lab and one current member remember their passwords. I was given the assignment of recovering 2TB of data from that laptop.

How does one go about reseting administrative password in Windows in particularly in the presence of TrueCrypt? If you are wondering I have never used Windows in my life so the only thing I usually with any Windows machine is just wipe out entire HDD and install OpenBSD.

Edit: I like the first idea but there is a big but. I have not mentioned that Windows XP has two HDD in the RAID 10 configuration. Obviously I am going to destroy RAID if I pull out HDD. I will analyze the rest of your answer but it looks like I am in big trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the drive, plug it in another machine where you have full admin access and then use Truecrypt to unlock the disk.

From there, you have many options. The simplest thing to do would be to simply recover the data you want from the drive: unless there is additional encryption (NTFS file encryption, for instance) you shouldn't have any issue doing that.

If you really want to recover access to the system's OS, you have several additional options:

- Uncrypt the volume in place and perform a regular recovery.
- Recover the SAM from the volume and use a password cracker on it (cain&Abel on Windows, John the ripper on any supported platform, hash suit on windows).
- Zero the admin account password in the SAM database directly (chntpw on Linux).

I need to add a work of warning: resetting any windows account password WILL make it impossible to recover any NTFS-encrypted files from that account. You can still recover them if you regain access to the password from another user who is in the file's access list, but there is no way to recover the file from the account after you've reset its password (that's also valid for regular password reset using the regular tools).